# Trying to create a formula that will pull all the non blank values ($ amounts) in a column from another tab

Tags: excel-formula

This is the only formula I have found that works so far for pulling in the amount:

=IFERROR(IF($B$7='Amount Owed'!$C$1,INDEX('Amount Owed'!$C$3:$C$13,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX('Amount Owed'!$C$3:$C$13>0,),0)),0),0)

This is the formula that I used to pull in the month:

=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($D$12,'Amount Owed'!C2:C13,0)),INDEX('Amount Owed'!A2:A13,MATCH($D$12,'Amount Owed'!C2:C13,0)),0)

I have worked on this for two days and have no idea what else to try! It pulls in the first dollar amount from the column, but it will not pull in the next. I am dealing with Office 2013 or 16, not exactly sure what one.

I have attached two snips of the spreadsheets. The first tab is the values that I want to pull into the second tab. In the table on the second tab, I want to pull in the red highlighted cells from the data on the first tab. The first cell should have the month and the cell under the **Line Total** should have the amount. I would like to be able to fill them both down so that all the months are showing that have amounts.

[Amounts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wry1D.png)
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLKCH.png)

Comment: If you can include a few table of your data and the output you want it would be easy to provide the answer

Comment: It's a little unclear what your data looks like, or what you are trying to do, or how you are using that formula.  I notice that all of your references are static, so they aren't going to change if you are expecting to copy them other places, and I also see that you are using MATCH with a fixed condition of TRUE and a fixed target range, so it is always going to return the same thing.  Also, MATCH returns one single value, so maybe that's the problem in expectation.  Again, hard to tell without a little bit of context.  I would suggest putting some sample data in a google sheet and sharing it.

Comment: What Excel version are you using? Office365 has FILTER formula that is useful for this

Comment: I am new to this but I changed my original post to include pictures of the spreadsheets. Thanks!